# How to disable Visual Studio warning C4244 for std::vector copy or assign with implicit narrowing conversion

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I **want** to perform a narrowing conversion of a vector of doubles to a vector of floats.  And I do not want Visual Studio throwing warning C4244, "possible loss of data", i.e. narrowing conversion.

Please do not post comments or answers saying I should not do this.  I am aware of the consequences.  I just want to suppress the warning.  It is not acceptable to disable the warning outside the scope of this specific function, e.g. globally via project settings.

I also want to use either vector::copy or vector::assign.  Avoiding the warning via transform() or for_each() with static_cast<> is.... just too explicit for my tastes.  So this questions is how to disable the warning, not avoid it.

My attempt at warning suppression does not work:

```
vector<float> DoubleVectorToFloat( vector<double> & x ){
  #pragma warning( push )
  #pragma warning( disable : 4244 ) 
  return vector<float>( x.begin(), x.end() );
  #pragma warning( pop )  
}
```

I understand that disabling warnings is bad.  But one size does not fit all.  My library is real-time, and processes 10's MiB/s.  I want template _Copy_unchecked1(etc) to be called; I do not want to pay the performance penalty of error checks.

Comment: Visual Studio allows disabling warning on a per file basis.  That's more than a specific function but could be acceptable in your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To disable this type of warning you may have to put this function into a module of its own and disable the warning at the top:

```
// top-of-file
#pragma warning( disable : 4244 ) 

// All your includes here

std::vector<float> DoubleVectorToFloat( std::vector<double> & x ){
  return std::vector<float>( x.begin(), x.end() );
}
// end-of-file
```

Comment: Thank you.  This answers the question as posed.  I agree with @bolov 's answer as the generally "correct" way to accomplish narrowing conversion of a vector, but that is not what I asked for.

Comment: I also agree with @bolov, but if someone else searches for this warning, then this may be the only solution.

Answer (score 5):

Use this instead:

```
std::vector<float> DoubleVectorToFloat(const std::vector<double>& x)
{
    std::vector<float> r;
    r.reserve(x.size());

    std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), std::back_inserter(r),
                   [](double a) { return static_cast<float>(a); });
    return r;
}
```

`std::transform` is the correct way to transform a vector of a type to a vector of another type.

I am **strongly** suggesting this approach as opposed to using the vector constructor and silencing the warning.

Comment: I'm hoping someone will post an answer that disables the warning, rather than avoiding it.  If not, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @TysonHilmer have you *verified* the performance difference between your original method and this?

Comment: @Caleth. For this specific function no.  But the last time I profiled reserve() followed by copy( , , back_inserter()), it was significantly slower than insert(). So I am reluctant to use it.  I just want simple implicit casting, without the complexity of extra code, and not to be told by Microsoft and the helpful folks on SO not to do this.  I know what I'm doing.